# Lookup value from dataframe with condition

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

I have a two data frames as mentioned below:

```
DF_1>
    Sr.No.  Stage           Time            Result          Result_2
    1       updated_date    1516868822411   1516868822361   1516868822350
    2       id              1516868822411   ABC             -
    3       engine_date     1516868822411   1516868822000   -
    4       blocked         1516868822411   80000           0
    5       updated_date    1516868822398   1516868822350   1516866877815
    6       list            1516868822398   BCD             -
    7       sub_stat_1      1516868779095   AC-12           AC-14
    8       status_1        1516868642468   AC-25           AC-38

DF_2>

Sr. No.     ID        Type_1 Type_2
1           AC-12      X      Y
2           AC-14      XX     YY
3           AC-25      A      B
4           AC-38      CC     CD
```

Now i want to vlookup value from DF_2 with below mentioned condition:

1. If Stage is sub_stat_1 then vlookup Result and Result_2 from Type_2 (From DF_2).
2. If stage is status_1 then vlookup Result and Result_2 from Type_1 (From DF_2).
3. If stage is status_1 or sub_stat_1 but Result or Result_2 is  then do nothing and give "-" value in output dataframe.
4. keep other values same as DF_1 Result and Result_2 to Desired output column Final_1 and Final_2, Respectively.
5. Whenever there are epoch time in Time, Result and Result_2 column if possible convert it to normal time in Desired output column Time_2, Final_1 and Final_2, Respectively.

Desired Output Dataframe:

```
Sr. No.    Stage   Time            Result          Result_2      Time_2                     Final_1                     Final_2
1      updated_date 1516868822411  1516868822361   1516868822350 25/01/2018 08:27:02        25/01/2018 08:27:02         25/01/2018 08:27:02
2      id           1516868822411  ABC             -             25/01/2018 08:27:02        ABC                         -
3      engine_date  1516868822411  1516868822000   -             25/01/2018 08:27:02        25/01/2018 08:27:02         -
4      blocked      1516868822411  80000           0             25/01/2018 08:27:02        80000                       0
5      updated_date 1516868822398  1516868822350   1516866877815 25/01/2018 08:27:02        25/01/2018 08:27:02         25/01/2018 07:54:38
6      list         1516868822398  BCD             -             25/01/2018 08:27:02        BCD                         -
7      sub_stat_1   1516868779095  AC-12           AC-14         25/01/2018 08:26:19        Y (Output of AC-12)         YY (Output of AC-14)
8      status_1     1516868642468  AC-25           AC-38         25/01/2018 08:24:02        A (Output of AC-25)         CC (Output of AC-38)
```

Comment: "than vlookup Result and Result_2 from Type_2" VLOOKUP is excel function (right?). It is merge in R. How can you merge Result and Result2 if they are in the same data frame?

Comment: @Mislav yes its a excel function but by vlookup means i want something that function to use in R to get desired output.

Comment: You can use `?match`.

Comment: @Gregor can you explain how to write that with if else condition which satisfy my all conditions as i have mentioned above.

Comment: @Mislav i don't have to merge since for each id there would be static value in Type_1 and Type_2 i just want to add three column in DF_1 Time_2, Final_1 and Final_2 where Time_2 give normal format of epoch time from DF_1 same in Final_1 and Final_2 will have same value as Result and Result_2 except (epoch time, status_1 and sub_stat_1) where status_1 and sub_stat_1 values comes from DF_2 as per id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your data frame columns are as printed, and your string columns are `character` type, not `factor`. Convert them to `character` if they are not already. (See sample data at bottom.)

```
# first we will create empty FINAL columns
DF_1$Final_1 = NA
DF_1$Final_2 = NA
```

> If Stage is sub_stat_1 then vlookup Result and Result_2 from Type_2 (From DF_2)

```
cond = DF_1[, 'Stage'] == "sub_stat_1"
from = "Type_2"
DF_1[cond, "Final_1"] = DF_2[match(DF_1[cond, "Result"], DF_2[, 'ID']), from]
DF_1[cond, "Final_2"] = DF_2[match(DF_1[cond, "Result_2"], DF_2[, 'ID']), from]
```

> If stage is status_1 then vlookup Result and Result_2 from Type_1 (From DF_2).

```
cond = DF_1[, 'Stage'] == "status_1"
from = "Type_1"
DF_1[cond, "Final_1"] = DF_2[match(DF_1[cond, "Result"], DF_2[, 'ID']), from]
DF_1[cond, "Final_2"] = DF_2[match(DF_1[cond, "Result_2"], DF_2[, 'ID']), from]
```

> If stage is status_1 or sub_stat_1 but Result or Result_2 is then do nothing and give "-" value in output dataframe.

I we initialized with missing values, `NA`. I'd encourage you to leave them as such, but if you really want you could do `DF_1[is.na(DF_1)] = "-"`.

> keep other values same as DF_1 Result and Result_2 to Desired output column Final_1 and Final_2, Respectively.

```
cond = ! DF_1[, 'Stage'] %in% c("status_1", "sub_stat_1")
DF_1[cond, "Final_1"] = DF_1[cond, "Result"]
DF_1[cond, "Final_2"] = DF_1[cond, "Result_2"]
```

> Whenever there are epoch time in Time, Result and Result_2 column if possible convert it to normal time in Desired output column Time_2, Final_1 and Final_2, Respectively.

I'll leave this one to you - you can use `as.POSIXct()` on your epoch times if you supply the origin, but your integers look too big to me. You may want to `format` them before inserting them into the Final columns so you can control what they look like as they get converted to characters. If you need more help with this, ask a separate question.

```
DF_1
#   Sr.No.        Stage         Time        Result      Result_2       Final_1       Final_2
# 1      1 updated_date 1.516869e+12 1516868822361 1516868822350 1516868822361 1516868822350
# 2      2           id 1.516869e+12           ABC             -           ABC             -
# 3      3  engine_date 1.516869e+12 1516868822000             - 1516868822000             -
# 4      4      blocked 1.516869e+12         80000             0         80000             0
# 5      5 updated_date 1.516869e+12 1516868822350 1516866877815 1516868822350 1516866877815
# 6      6         list 1.516869e+12           BCD             -           BCD             -
# 7      7   sub_stat_1 1.516869e+12         AC-12         AC-14             Y            YY
# 8      8     status_1 1.516869e+12         AC-25         AC-38             A            CC
```

---

Using this data:

```
DF_1
#   Sr.No.  Stage         Time        Result      Result_2       Final_1       Final_2
# 1  updated_date 1.516869e+12 1516868822361 1516868822350 1516868822361 1516868822350
# 2            id 1.516869e+12           ABC             -           ABC             -
# 3   engine_date 1.516869e+12 1516868822000             - 1516868822000             -
# 4       blocked 1.516869e+12         80000             0         80000             0
# 5  updated_date 1.516869e+12 1516868822350 1516866877815 1516868822350 1516866877815
# 6          list 1.516869e+12           BCD             -           BCD             -
# 7    sub_stat_1 1.516869e+12         AC-12         AC-14             Y            YY
# 8      status_1 1.516869e+12         AC-25         AC-38             A            CC
```

---

Using this data:

```
DF_1 = read.table(text = "Sr.No.  Stage       Time            Result      

    Result_2
    1   updated_date    1516868822411   1516868822361   1516868822350
    2   id              1516868822411   ABC             -
    3   engine_date     1516868822411   1516868822000   -
    4   blocked         1516868822411   80000           0
    5   updated_date    1516868822398   1516868822350   1516866877815
    6   list            1516868822398   BCD             -
    7   sub_stat_1      1516868779095   AC-12           AC-14
    8   status_1        1516868642468   AC-25           AC-38", check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = T)

DF_2 = read.table(text = "Sr.No. ID     Type_1 Type_2
1   AC-12      X      Y
2   AC-14      XX     YY
3   AC-25      A      B
4   AC-38      CC     CD", check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = T)
```

Comment: Why did you use Sr. No.??

Comment: Because your question made it look like part of the column name. This should be easy enough for you to adapt to your actual data. Use `dput()` to provide copy/pasteable data if you want answers to have the exact same inputs.

Comment: sorry it was my bad, now i have modified the answer. it will give you exact idea of data frame.

Comment: It's working find though getting this error: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cond, "Final_2", value = list(1516868822350,  :
  provided 272 variables to replace 1 variables

Comment: Getting this error where sub_stat_1 and status_1 not available and it give some random value in Final_1 and Final_2 (i.e Final_1 = 1516868822361 & Final_2 = 1516868822350)

Comment: I can't reproduce - the code works just fine on the sample data. Are you able to get the sample data to work okay? And you made sure the columns are of class `character`?